# Is there any good software that solves equations of permutation group elements?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, math-software, computational-algebra, constraint-programming

I need to solve equations of permutation group elements (elements of $S_n$) that may not may not have solutions.
The number of equations generally exceeds the number of variables.
Is there any good software that can do this? If not, is there any method for me to do that on paper in an efficient way? Thank you very much!

One of the problems is:
$p_{ij}\in S_3$ for $0\leq i<j\leq 3$. $p_{ij}$ has to satisfy the following conditions:

(1) $p_{12}p_{01}p_{23}=id$

(2) $p_{12}p_{23}p_{01}=id$

(3) $p_{01}p_{02}p_{12}p_{23}=(12)$

(4) $p_{01}p_{02}p_{23}p_{13}p_{12}=(132)$

(5) $p_{01}p_{23}p_{03}p_{13}p_{02}p_{12}=(13)$

(6) $p_{01}p_{23}p_{03}p_{02}p_{13}p_{12}=(13)$

(7) $p_{23}p_{13}p_{12}p_{01}=(23)$

(8) $p_{23}p_{13}p_{01}p_{02}p_{12}=(123)$

(9) $p_{23}p_{01}p_{03}p_{13}p_{02}p_{12}=(13)$

(10) $p_{23}p_{01}p_{03}p_{02}p_{13}p_{12}=(13)$

(11) $p_{01}$ and $p_{23}$ commutes.

(12) $p_{02}$ and $p_{13}$ commutes.

This particular problem can be simplified by reducing all sequences on the left that differ only by permuting adjacent commuting elements. So (2),(6),(9) and (10) can be removed.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? If you will write the permutations as matrices, then perhaps the many matrix computation packages will be useful.

Comment: @user226970 Use representation theory? Yes I can do it..I will search SageMath and others now..

Comment: Please be more specific. [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) has an extensive functionality for [permutations](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap42.html) and for their [groups](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap43.html) but without further details it's hard to say. It may happen that the way of solving the problem is outside permutation groups.

Comment: Thank you for the example - that's interesting! Do you have only one system per group? Do you have another one for $S_2$? In these systems, are you conjecturing that they have no solution, or there may be some which have solutions?

Comment: The one for $S_2$ is very simple:
$p_{12}p_{01}=id$,
$p_{01}p_{02}p_{12}=(12)$ which obviously have two solutions.

Comment: Very good, that's useful as a simple test case if someone would be working on the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are just $6^6$ possible assignments of permutations to variables to check, so a brute-force solution is probably the simplest in this case.

In general, you want to enumerate the possible solutions, using the equations as early as possible to cut down on the branching. The more equations the better! Thus in this case you might have pseudocode something like

```
for each p01 in S3
  for each p23 that commutes with p01
     p12 = p23^(-1) p01^(-1)  # from equation (1)
     p02 = p01^(-1) (12) p23^(-1) p12^(-1) # from equation (3)
     p13 = p23^(-1) p12^(-1) p01^(-1) (123) p12^(-1) # from equation (4)
     if p13 commutes with p02
        p03 = p23^(-1) p01^(-1) (13) p12^(-1) p02^(-1) p13^(-1)
        if (all the other conditions hold)
           print solution (p01 p02 p03 p12 p13 p23)
```

---

Update by Alexander K.: just to illustrate how this pseudocode may be straightforwardly rewritten in GAP :

```
S3:=SymmetricGroup(3);
for p01 in S3 do
  for p23 in Centraliser(S3,p01) do
    p12 := p23^(-1)*p01^(-1); # from equation (1)
    p02 := p01^(-1)*(1,2)*p23^(-1)*p12^(-1); # from equation (3)
    p13 := p23^(-1)*p12^(-1)*p01^(-1)*(1,2,3)*p12^(-1); # from equation (4)
    if p13*p02 = p02*p13 then
      p03 := p23^(-1)*p01^(-1)*(1,3)*p12^(-1)*p02^(-1)*p13^(-1);
      if true then # replace by checking that all the other conditions hold
        Print([p01,p02,p03,p12,p13,p23],"\n");
      fi;
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

Pasting it in GAP produces five solutions - if you will extend it by adding further checks, there may be less.

Comment: I have a lot of cases that are way worse. At least 100 equations in $S_4$, at least 2980 equations in $S_5$ and....After identifying equations that only differ by commutations $S_4$ case will be reduced to 25-40 equations and $S_5$ case can also be reduced to less than 200 equations.

I know brute-force but is there any better methods?

Comment: It seems that you do really need some machinery to be able to solve them systematically. If you would have just one system, one could hope to optimise pruning branches earlier enough by looking at relations and arranging loops in a good order, like in this answer, but the perspective of doing this for lots of systems with lots of relations looks pretty challenging. Maybe one could try to look at relations and apply some rewriting systems, or use representations to map relations to matrix equations and then try to solve those. Or maybe to tackle the original problem (which one?) differently...

Comment: I suggest to look at this as a constraint satisfaction problem, and use constraint modelling tools, e.g. [these](http://constraintmodelling.org/tools/) to find solutions. E.g., you may represent permutations as arrays, where `s[i]` is the image of `i` - these will be the search variables. Each identity for $S_n$ leads to $n$ constraints, describing images of each of the $n$ points. E.g. if `a[1..3]` and `b[1..3]` represent two permutations and their product $ab$ (from left to right) is $(1,2)$, then `b[a[1]]=2`, `b[a[2]]=1,` `b[a[3]]=3`. Generating constraints from relations may be automated.

Comment: Thanks - I've just added a GAP example following your pseudocode.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Excellent! Is it more efficient to test every $p_{23}$ to see if it commutes with $p_{01}$, or to loop over $p_{23}$ in the centralizer? (I know in MAGMA I would do "for $p_{23}$ in Centralizer($S_{3}$, $p_{01}$)" and it is pretty efficient for permutation groups.)

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Great idea! Just updated the code to use it.

Comment: I have modified the code to add more equations and remove typos. This works..

Comment: S3:=SymmetricGroup(3);
for p01 in S3 do
  for p23 in Centraliser(S3,p01) do
    p12 := p23^(-1)*p01^(-1); # from equation (1)
    p02 := p01^(-1)*(1,2)*p23^(-1)*p12^(-1); # from equation (3)
    p13 := p23^(-1)*p02^(-1)*p01^(-1)*(1,2,3)*p12^(-1); # from equation (4)
    if p13*p02 = p02*p13 then
      p03 := p23^(-1)*p01^(-1)*(1,3)*p12^(-1)*p13^(-1)*p02^(-1); # from equation (5)
      if p23*p13*p12*p01=(2,3) then 
           if p23*p13*p01*p02*p12=(1,3,2) then
          Print([p01,p02,p03,p12,p13,p23],"\n");
 fi;
      fi;
    fi;
  od;
od;

Comment: @YingZhou: that's good. Have you managed to do something with larger groups?

Comment: @YingZhou: which typos, by the way? You can suggest an edit to the answer to fix typos, if any.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalev It has been fixed in my comment which I will put in the answer later..

Comment: For larger groups I have to first generate these equations which I will try using Java..

Answer (score 2):

I am actually going to back up the answer (in slightly more generality) given by Robert Israel, and address the comments you made there.

I would guess that the number of equations is not a big problem, the difficulty will be more focused on the number of variables (involved in each equation) and the size of the group.  The reason why it is not a big deal if there are say 200 equations is that only a very small collection of elements are going to satisfy more than a small number of the equations; as soon as one is failed, you can stop.  Moreover, you can use a collection of equation involving only a small subset of the variables as an intermediate step.

That being said, you can use your equations to shrink down the number of variables to consider by a large margin.  In your example, you can deduce that $p_{01}$ and $p_{23}$ commute, so $p_{23}$ is in the centralizer of $p_{12}$.  Then using the other equations you can show that 
$$\begin{array}{ll}
p_{02} & = p_{01}^{-1}(1 \ 2)p_{01}\\
p_{12} & = p_{01}^{-1}p_{23}^{-1}\\
p_{13} & = (1 \ 2 \ 3)p_{01}^{-1}p_{23}^{-1}\\
p_{03} & = p_{01}^{-1}p_{23}^{-1}(1 \ 3)p_{23}(1 \ 2)p_{01}(1 \ 2 \ 3)p_{01}^{-1}p_{23}^{-1} 
\end{array}$$
By making $6$ choices of $p_{01}$ and then choosing $p_{23}$ from the centralizer, there are only $11$ total possibilities instead of $6^6$.

Starting with $10$ variables in $S_{5}$ gives $120^{10}$ possible selections, which is a lot to "brute force" through, but if you bring it down to really choosing maybe $7$ variables (or possibly less), and each chosen from some restricted subset of $S_{5}$, it is realistic to loop through no matter how many equations.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added an example to Robert Israel's answer to show how to do this in GAP. Indeed, why not to try to do this in GAP and see how far one could get with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a constraint solver, such as Savile Row ( http://savilerow.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/ ). While this tool does not support permutations, and permutation multiplication, directly, you can map the problem to integers fairly easily.

This wouldn't use any group theory techniques at all, just tackle the problem as permutations with search, but the performance would (I expect) be very good. If you want, I could write an example of how to transform your problem into the input of Savile Row.